# Is there any way to split vertical monitor into two on Windows 10 and use fullscreen mode on videos?

Tags: windows-10, video, display, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I have a secondary monitor that I use in a vertical orientation. I would like to put one window in the upper half and another in the lower. I was able to achieve this by using PowerToys FancyZones but when I try to put a video in fullscreen it naturally occupies the whole monitor and leaves me with gigantic black bars. Is there any way to make the video "go fullscreen" only on the top half of the monitor?

Comment: Dell does it with some of their screens: you can "hard-split" them in a way that Windows recognizes each half as 2 separate displays. But I believe part of the magic is in the screen itself, on top of the Dell app. There are also paid solutions that may work for any monitor, see https://www.digitaltigers.com/ultraview-desktop-manager.asp.